# Как более разумно хранить комментарии в БД?

Tags: mysql, php, комментарии

Подскажите пожалуйста, как более разумно хранить комментарии в БД? Такая ситуация: нужно реализовать комментирование в "блоге" и в "Фотоальбоме". Вот какие у меня самой мысли, либо сделать одну таблицу с полями

```
id-ключ
text-текст коммента
page_id-id страницы на которой сам коммент
name-имя пользователя
type-тип, "Блог", либо "Фотоальбом"
```

Либо же создать две таблицы без поля "type" - одну на фото, другую на блог. Как будет правильнее? Хотелось бы услышать совет профессионалов, но вот вдруг мне придет в голову ещё что нибудь закомментировать...каждый раз создавать таблицу? Или первый вариант подойдет, и сразу наводка, как доставать эти комментарии, чтобы скорость не оставляла желать лучшего, может есть какой нить

```
SELECT
```

У которого можно передать сразу несколько параметров

```
WHERE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однозначного решения тут нет. Можно держать одну таблицу на все комментарии, можно на каждый вид держать свою.

Решение зависит от вас.

- Если комментарии рассматриваются как отдельная сущность, т.е., например, есть поиск по комментариям (вне зависимости от того, к какому контенту они были добавлены), удобнее, конечно, чтоб это была одна таблица. Тут надо позаботиться об индексах. Использование несколько таблиц не противоречит возможности поиска union'ом из select'ов.
- Если родительские структуры обособлены (на блог и фотоальбом свои таблицы), вполне логично разделять и комментарии. И объединенная таблица не противоречит этой логике, разделение по типу, даст тот же эффект.

ЗЫ Конечно, если речь не идет о гигантской базе с миллиардами комментариев. Там подход не с точки зрения "что будет если я захочу еще что-нить комментировать", а "как обеспечить скорость" и "как бы партицировать данные"...

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения! Я выбрала первый вариант, так как думаю больше 1к сообщений не будет

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал с type.
А выводить можно так:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `type` = 'blog' AND `page_id` = '1'
```